# Modifying \everydisplay causes the align* environment to stop working

Tags: equations

I want all displayed mathematics in my document to be typeset in the style of inline mathematics. In his answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/size-of-math-equations-in-latex), Matthew Leingang explains how to do the opposite (typeset all inline mathematics in the style of displayed mathematics) by carefully modifying the `\everymath` token list. Reasoning by analogy I figured that the following test document ought to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,fullpage}

\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\textstyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}x
&=\sum_{i=1}^{10}i^2\\
&=t^3+\int_3^9y^a\,\mathrm{d}y\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

But it does not. When trying to compile this document, TeXWorks gives the following error:

```
! Improper \halign inside $$'s.
<recently read> \halign
```

The code it displays, as though to draw my attention to a mistake, is the code in the vicinity of `\end{align*}`. This error does not appear if the line in the preamble modifying `\everydisplay` is commented out. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internall, `align` uses alignment displays, described p. 190 of the TeXbook as follows:

> TeX also allows "alignment displays" [...] 
>   An alignment display is created by commands of the general form
>
> ```
> $$ <assignments> \halign{ <alignment> } <assignments> $$
> ```
>
> where the `<assignments>` [...] do not produce any math lists.

But `\textstyle` is not an assignment: in fact, it starts a math list. So `\halign` is not alone in that equation anymore, and TeX complains.

Now a solution: since `align` builds a construction like `$\displaystyle ...$` internally, we can redefine the size using `\let\displaystyle\textstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\let\displaystyle\textstyle

An example of aligned equations,
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} &= \frac{\sqrt{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{2}
&\frac{\sqrt{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{2} &= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} 
\\
\frac{\sqrt{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{2} &= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} 
&\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} &= \frac{\sqrt{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{2}
\end{align}
which seem to work.

But the \verb|equation| environment won't:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}}{2} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{y^2}{2} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You might prefer saving the definition before using `\let\olddisplaystyle\displaystyle` in case you need it.

Comment: Ah, also a good idea. But can you explain why the code in the OP doesn't compile?

Comment: @Hendrik: I added something, but I'm not quite sure _why_ alignment displays are useful, rather than just using an `\halign` outside a display.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the suggested workaround, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A partial workaround is to define some macros that can be used to replace the `\[ ... \]` and `align*` environments. Regard the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,fullpage}

\newcommand{\t}{\textstyle}
\newcommand{\blob}[1]{\[\t#1\]}
\newcommand{\calc}[2]{\begin{align*}\t#1&\t#2\end{align*}}
\newcommand{\nl}{\\&\t}

\begin{document}

\blob{4^x + 5^y = 6^z \quad\mathrm{unless}\quad x = \frac{y}{z}}

\calc{x}{
    =\sum_{i=1}^{10} i^2 \nl
    \leq t^3 + \int_3^9y^a\,\mathrm{d}y
}

\end{document}
```

This gives displayed mathematics typeset as inline maths, and provides commands that do pretty much what I want and make for readable enough code. For unusual cases where `\blob` and `\calc` are not good enough, at least `\t` is reasonably concise, even if it does have to be just about everywhere.

This isn't a real answer to my question, though. I'd still like to know what the deal is with the original problem...