# Why does \everydisplay conflict with gather and multline

Tags: errors, amsmath, hooks

When `gather*` is used together with `\everydisplay` an error is produced. Is there a possibility to make these work together?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\everydisplay{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
1+\cos x
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Modifying \everydisplay causes the align* environment to stop working](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11778/1235).

Comment: Please consider accepting some answers of your other questions by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\everydisplay`, `\everymath` could be used. This applies to `gather` as well. To avoid coloring of inline math, you could check if you are within `gather` or `align` similar to amsmath's own checks.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}
\newcommand*{\eqcolor}{\color{blue}}
\makeatletter
\everymath{%
  \ifingather@ \eqcolor%
    \else \ifinalign@ \eqcolor
      \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
1+\cos x
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
1+\cos x
\end{align*}
\centering $1 + \cos x$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, inline math is not colored. Regarding other displayed math: instead of `equation` or `\[ ... \]` you could use `gather` or `gather*`, respectively. This could be done in the preamble, without changes to equation environments in the text, such as

```
\let\equation\gather
\let\endequation\endgather
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just say `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}`, then the previous content of it gets erased and you will have these kind of problems. The right way to use `\everydisplay` is:

```
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay \color{blue}}
```

Then no problem should happen.

Comment: With `gather` and this definition the same error occurs (`! Improper \halign inside $$'s.`)

Comment: Also doesn't work with align