# Using `\everydisplay` crashes split environment

Tags: amsmath, displaystyle

I use TeX Live 2020 on Debian Testing; version of `amsmath` is 2.17e. I have noticed that I get the error

> Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here. \end{split}

whenever there is an `\everydisplay` command and try to use the `split` env. within **any** math environment, whether display math (any delimiter), equation, `eqnarray`, and their starred versions. Here's a MnWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\everydisplay{\color{blue}}

\let\equation\gather
\let\endequation\endgather

\begin{document}

Line.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a & = b\\
c & = d
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried using the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13592/why-does-everydisplay-conflict-with-gather-and-multline) by modifying `\equation` using `\let` as seen above, but it doesn't work.

Is this some sort of bug? Should I report this somewhere? Is it just me? The only reference to this error in the `amsmath` doc. is the description of split ("it is not standalone" etc).

Comment: note you have redefined equation but not endequation `\let\endequatoin\endgather`

Comment: Related: you have a typo in the `\endequat....` part. Though split really does not like that `\everydisplay`. I hardly ever use `split` anymore, if you don't redefine `equation` and use `aligned` instead of `split` then it works just fine. Unrelated: I'd use `xcolor` instead of `color` it can do more.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it seems to give an error even when one does spell correctly?

Comment: @daleif sure but at least it has a chance of working

Comment: Right, got the typo. Still doesn't work. The error changes, though: ` Improper \halign inside $$'s. \next@ ...skip \z@skip \global \row@ \@ne \halign                                                to\displaywidth \bgroup \s...`. No matter, the point is that split doesn't work when using `\everydisplay`.

Comment: My solution works with TL2020

Comment: Okay, I can use `aligned`, but I'd still want to know why this happens. :)

Comment: Color is a strange beast and so is table like constructions. (align, split etc are table like constructions). And so things needs to be added to a "good" way. And that is probably not the case here. Given that not may people chooses to change the color of every equation, this has not been dealt with (it will probably need a rewrite of certain parts of amsmath).

Comment: Right. Color was just an example. I still get the error even if I just type `\everydisplay{}`. I'll use other environments if I have this command present. Thanks. :)