# How do I get different colors for math and for text?

Tags: math-mode, color

I want to include something in my LaTeX article that will make all mathematical formulae appear in black, while all text (including everything inside `\text{}`s in the middle of mathematical formulae) appear in red.  Ideally I would like this to be something I could include in the preamble or in a `.cls` file or something like that.  What would be the quickest way to do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A quick way is using `\everymath`, `\everydisplay` and the `everysel` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{\color{red}}
\everymath{\color{black}}
\everydisplay{\color{black}}
\begin{document}
text $x=0$
\[ \text{Text in math, }y= 1 \]
\end{document}
```

[image: color in text and math]

However, with more complicated `amsmath` environments such as `align` there could could be problems with `\everydisplay`, see: [Modifying \everydisplay causes the align environment to stop working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11778/modifying-everydisplay-causes-the-align-environment-to-stop-working). If you would like to go this way, perhaps omit `\everydisplay` as `align` uses inline math internally, and redefine basic displayed math otherwise for using the desired color.

Comment: But you're right; this does produce an error when I combine it with the `IEEEeqnarray` from the `IEEEtrantools` package.  I tried redefining `equation` s and the `\[ ... \]` so that they behaved as `gather` s and I could get away without the `\everydisplay`, but that didn't work very well.  What sort of thing did you have in mind when you talked about redefining basic displayed math otherwise?

Comment: Update: replacing the `everydisplay` with `\let\originaldisplaystyle\displaystyle
\renewcommand\displaystyle{\color{black}\originaldisplaystyle}` stopped the errors, and everything inside `align` s or `IEEEeqnarray` s is beautiful and black (or red, if it's marked as being text); however, normal `equation` s now render in red rather than in black, since `displaystyle` is not part of the definition for `equation`.  Is there some way of suppressing `everydisplay` so that it only affects the `equation` environment?

Comment: @Donkey_2009: Redefining `equation` would be an option.

Comment: Thanks - I've now done that (using `\let\oldeq\equation
\def\equation{\oldeq\color{black}} `) but for some reason I can't do the same for the `equation*` environment: I keep getting errors.  What is the problem here?

Comment: @Donkey_2009: This could be a news question on the site, better than in a comment - how to redefine the `equation*` environment of amsmath.

Answer (score 16):

If you can use `xelatex` or `lualatex` to compile the document, a combination of `fontspec` and `unicode-math` can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Color=FF0000]{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont[Color=FF0000]{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont[Color=FF0000]{Latin Modern Mono}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color=000000]{lmmath-regular.otf}

\begin{document}
A bunch of text, then an equation.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \sin (x) \text{ and } g(x) = e^x\cos(x)
\end{equation}
Some \textsf{inline} math \( a = b \), and then an \texttt{align}
\begin{align}
 N^2 &= -\frac{g}{\rho_0} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z} \\
   N &= \sqrt{-\frac{g}{\rho_0} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I am trying to compile your example, but setting black for text and red for math I get funny result when most math is red, but some elements (horizontal lines in fractions and roots) are still black. Is this a bug of unicode-math?

Comment: @Misha I honestly don't know, perhaps it has to with how those lines are rendered. Edit: I would recommend asking a follow-up question about this.