# Redefining the amsmath equation* environment

Tags: equations, environments, amsmath, starred-version

For the background to this, see [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37319/how-do-i-get-different-colors-for-math-and-for-text/37324#37324)

I've been trying to make changes in my LaTeX document so that math displays in black and text in red.  Thanks to Stefan Kottwitz and Torbjørn T. I've been able to go some way towards doing this.  At the moment I have

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everysel}
\EverySelectfont{\color{red}}
\everymath{\color{black}}

\let\originaldisplaystyle\displaystyle
\renewcommand\displaystyle{\color{black}\originaldisplaystyle}

\let\oldeq\equation
\def\equation{\oldeq\color{black}}
```

This changes the text color to red, and then changes the colors for inline math, `align` environment and `equation` environment to black.  This all works fine.  However, when I try to make similar changes to the `equation*` environment:

```
\let\oldeq*\equation*
\def\equation*{\oldeq*\color{black}}
```

I get errors.  My guess is that the compiler is reading `\equation*` as `\equation` followed by a text asterisk: if I type

```
\newenvironment{oldeq*}{\equation*}{\endequation*}
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\begin{oldeq*}}{\end{oldeq*}}
```

then the document compiles, but the `\equation*` environment now renders as the `\equation` environment (i.e. with numbering) but with an asterisk placed before the equation.  This is the only thing that I have managed to get to compile so far.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a redefinition based on the original `amsmath` definition together with the color command:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \color{black}
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

A simpler solution, which also doesn't need to know amsmath's internals, is possible with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation*}{\color{black}}
```

Comment: Thanks SO much: everything's running really well now.  I had tried copying in the `amsmath` definition, but I missed out the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` so it didn't work.

Comment: This is very helpful. Writing a small document where my math is a unique color for visibility, I combined this an `\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{mathBlue}}` to ensure my math is all blue WITHOUT breaking my `equation*` environments. Only downside is I need to do this for all math envs to avoid issues seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347268/227616), [and here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48191/227616), [and also here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37324/227616). This is perfect for my hacked together small use-case!