# Change math color globally

Tags: math-mode, color

I would like to change the color of anything that is in mathematical mode, in all my document.

Is it possible?

---

PS: The solution I've found so far is

```
\everymath{\color{red}}
\everydisplay{\color{red}}
\def\m@th{\normalcolor\mathsurround\z@}
```

but it cancels the command `\everymath{\displaystyle}`

Comment: Could you please show us a MWE, what you already have tried?

Comment: I havent tried anything. I need to redefine `$[...]$` and `$$[...]$$`... I don't know how to start.

Comment: Start with not using `$$ ... $$`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. `\everymath{\color{red}}
\everydisplay{\color{red}}
\def\m@th{\normalcolor\mathsurround\z@}` made it.