# Color - How to make a few letters in an equation have color

Tags: beamer, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to color math symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols)

I have an equation: y = 2x + 3.  How would I make the 2x red in equation mode in beamer?

Comment: For `beamer`, perhaps [coloured math in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37541/coloured-math-in-beamer) is a better duplicate.

Comment: @PeterGrill: But would the solution suggested in that answer work for just parts of an equation? It seems like it just explains how to switch the colour for maths stuff in general.

Comment: @Jake: Obviously I have not had enough coffee today... You are correct. So the first one is probably a better duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{Kaare Mikkelsen}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Colors}
\begin{equation}
\textcolor{red}{e}=\textcolor{blue}{m}\textcolor{green}{c}^2
\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

if you look into the documentation of the graphicx package (http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx), you can also define your own colors.