# Set math fonts to predefined color

Tags: beamer, math-mode, equations, color

I am trying to define math text is some predefined color as in my preamble:

```
\setbeamercolor{math text}{pmsGreen}
\everymath{\color{pmsGreen}}
\everydisplay{\relax \ifx \\\@eqncr \else \color{pmsGreen}\fi }
```

NB: I have not understood the last line, just found it somewhere.
But the problem is while mathmode is in pmsGreen, text inside eqnarray is still in default color.
How can I manage this?

EDIT: A minimal example:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\definecolor{pmsGreen}{RGB}{0,156,121}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{pmsGreen}
\everymath{\color{pmsGreen}}
\everydisplay{\relax \ifx \\\@eqncr \else \color{pmsGreen}\fi }
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}

\begin{document}
$1=2$
\begin{eqnarray}
  1=2\\
  2=3
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

NB: I have seen examples where the sample code shows the output as well, dont know how to do that.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example?

Comment: The `1=2` in `quotation` is not marked as math, so TeX considers it normal text.

Comment: sorry for this mistake; actual problem is updated. it is in eqnarray

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37541/86 and the questions/answers linked therein.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting the manual:

> **Beamer-Color math text**
>
> This color is the parent of math text inlined and math text displayed. It is empty by default. See
>   those colors for details.
>
> **Beamer-Color math text displayed**
>
> Color parents: math text
>
> Like math text inlined, only for so-called “displayed” mathematical text. This is mathematical text between [ and ] or between $$ and $$ or inside environments like equation or align. The setup of this color is somewhat fragile, use at your own risk. The background is currently ignored.

So, you have to exploit:

```
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=pmsGreen}
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=pmsGreen}
```

to have also equations in `align` colored (avoid using eqnarray, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)).

An example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,xcolor=dvipsnames,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\definecolor{pmsGreen}{RGB}{0,156,121}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=pmsGreen}
\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=pmsGreen}
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
$1=2$
\begin{quotation}
  1=2
\end{quotation}

\begin{equation}
x+y=100
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  1=2 \\
  2=3
\end{align}
\begin{itemize}
\item \only<2>{Contains essentially \textit{all} physical information of a given system} $A(\vec{r},\vec{r}^{'})=-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\im\Tr\int^{\mu}_{\curvearrowright} dz~\hat{A}~G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^{'};z)$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `\everymath` and `\everydisplay`? I'd remove those lines; in any case, the second one should go between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't check their meaning: just copied and paste from OP's code. I'll have a look in the beamer's manual for further explanation before removing them :)

Comment: Cannot explain, but
 \item \only<2>{Contains essentially \textit{all} physical information of a given system}
      $A(\vec{r},\vec{r}^{'})=-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\im\Tr\int^{\mu}_{\curvearrowright} dz~\hat{A}~G(\vec{r},\vec{r}^{'};z)$\
requires \everymath

Comment: @Rudra: no, I've tested that example and it works too.

Comment: If you want to keep a separate color for `\text{}` in math mode, try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506844/135922)