# Color for math applies to \text{} and \intertext{} as well

Tags: beamer, color

I have a LaTeX beamer presentation where I use `\setbeamercolor{math text}` for enhanced readability and it works great.  Unfortunately, all `\text{}` and `\intertext{}` is colored as well and that doesn't look nice.  Is there any remedy?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a term in math mode: $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

This is color inside of \texttt{align*}, but the text is colored as well:
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 && \text{(Pythagoras)}. \\
\intertext{Even worse, the intertext is colored as well:}
a^1 + b^1 = c^1 && \text{(me)}.
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And it produces this output:

[image]

**Update:** @Mico has provided a nice solution that works well, even for inline-math in `\intertext`, but it colors tables as well!  Can that be avoided?

Plus, `\text` does switch back to black, but math in `\text` then stays black.  Have a look at the `\text` with `$x$` in `\underbrace`.

Here is an updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}
%\newcommand\blackintertext[1]{\intertext{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}

\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}
\let\origtext\text
\renewcommand\text[1]{\origtext{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a term in inline-math mode: $1+1=2$.

Displayed equations are colored as well \dots
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{a^2 + b^2}_{\text{magic $x$}} &= c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} \\
\intertext{\dots\ but, happily, intertext material is no longer colored. Even $\pi \approx 3.14$ is colored.}
e^{i\pi} + 1 &= 0 \tag{Euler}
\end{align*}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
What & about \\
\hline
a    & table?
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like:[image]

Comment: just define a command say `\newcommand\blackintertext[1]{\intertext{\textcolor{black}{#1}}` and use that instead of `\intertext`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: simple solution, but then math in `\intertext` is no longer colored!

Comment: I don't see why not, the nested math should trigger your `\everymath` setting to make the nested math blue

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you use the MWE and toggle the comment chars on the `\blackintertext` instead of the `\everymath` you can verify it. Plus, the tags are in blue as well. But the table is OK :)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you replace

```
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}
```

with

```
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}
```

Moreover, to typeset equation "tags", use the `\tag` macro.

[image]

To "fix" the behavior of the `\text` macro, i.e., to make it output its argument in black, I suggest you add the following two instructions to the preamble:

```
\let\origtext\text
\renewcommand\text[1]{\origtext{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}
```

---

Here's the code that generates the screenshot shown above:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=blue}
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is a term in inline-math mode: $1+1=2$.

Displayed equations are colored as well \dots
\begin{gather*}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} \\
\intertext{\dots\ but, happily, intertext material is no longer colored.}
e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0 \tag{Euler}
\end{gather*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a nice solution, but now `tabular` environments are colored as well. See above for a new MWE.

Comment: @cxxl use `\begin{tabular}[t]{lll}` the `[t]` should avoid math mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, it doesn't. The table is still blue.

Comment: @cxxl probably beamer doing something weird:-) sorry can't test at present

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I just checked if the `tabular` color anomaly happens in the `article` document class as well (in addition to the `beamer` class) -- and it does. :-( It happens both with `\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath\color{blue}}` (as practiced above) and with `\everymath{\color{blue}}`. I have no idea what might be going on.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your help so far, gentlemen. Can this maybe be solved by wrapping the `\tabular` and resetting the color before it?

Comment: @cxxl - "Wrapping" the `tabular` material in `\begingroup\color{black}` and `\endgroup` doesn't seem to achieve the desired result. :-(