# LaTeX command for equal (=)

Tags: macros, symbols

Is there a LaTeX command for the equal (`=`) sign? I'd like to overwrite the command so that all equal signs in my document are colored green. But it seems I cannot do it with just the symbol `=`, which is not a command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ten years later, a better implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% preserve the original equals
% and make = math active
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\standardequals=\mathcode`=
  \mathcode`="8000
}

% define math active = to be green \standardequals
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mika_greenequals: { \mathcolor{green!70!red}{\standardequals} }
\char_set_active_eq:NN = \mika_greenequals:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$a\standardequals b$

$a=b$

\end{document}
```

The top line is to show that spacing is right.

[image]

###### original answer

Every character can be turned into a command in math mode, but some special tricks are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`=
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathrel{\textcolor{green}{\standardequals}}}

\edef\standardequals{\mathchar\the\mathcode`=\relax}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`=\string"8000 }

\begin{document}
$a=b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the code is not too long, could you please explain how it works too, egreg? Thanks!

Comment: I'm asking also because I'd like to do other characters, like > < ) ( etc.

Comment: @MikaH. It works similar to the accepted answer of [LaTeX color setting for math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100619).