# How to escape = in LaTeX's for loop

Tags: symbols, loops

In user700902's answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100619/latex-color-setting-for-math-mode), there is the following for-loop:

```
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\do{%
\expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{green}}
```

If I want to put symbols like `>`, `(`, `=` along with `a,b,c,...`, how can I escape them?

Whole Document:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,hyperref,color,xcolor}

\newcommand*{\mathcolor}{}
\def\mathcolor#1#{\mathcoloraux{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mathcoloraux}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\def\colorizemath #1#2{%
    \expandafter\mathchardef\csname orig:math:#1\endcsname\mathcode`#1
    \mathcode`#1="8000
    \toks@\expandafter{\csname orig:math:#1\endcsname}%
    \begingroup
       \lccode`~=`#1
       \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
       \edef~{{\noexpand\color{#2}\the\toks@}}}%
   }
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:==\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{brown}}
\def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\color{black}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Test File}

\author{ABC}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The equation $1+1=2$ holds.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Except for braces, the symbols you mention can be inserted without escaping

Comment: @JLDiaz I don't think so... I did `\@for\@tempa:==\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{green}}` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikaH. It works for me. Are you sure, you are between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`? Otherwise, explain what *doesn’t work*. Error message? Faulty output? Unexpected issues? (Unrelated to the question: `=` looses its `\mathrel` status with this.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Not sure how helpful this is, but what happens is: It doesn't compile, and the error message is `! Bad mathchar (32768). <to be read again> \relax l.26 \begin{document}`
And yes, I'm between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @MikaH. this is why you should always post a complete document that shows the problem, most likely it is nothing to do with for loop but the syntax required of an assignment the `=` is optional except when it isn't for example `\let\a b` is the same as `\let\a=b` but if you want `b` to be `=` you have to have `\let\a==` as teh first `=` is taken as part of the assignment.

Comment: I've just posted the whole document. Could you please take a look and see where the problem is?

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with the loop: it's `hyperref` trying to save the mathcode of `=`. Probably one for Heiko Oberdiek! (You can't `\mathchardef` something that's set to math active, which is where the issue is.)

Comment: This "colorization" will most probably break a number of constructs. Moreover the spacing for `=` will be wrong. If the line ``\mathcode `#1="8000`` is turned into ``\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode `#1="8000 }`` the error disappears.

Comment: Ah, it's `amsmath` that is trying to save the math code, not `hyperref`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid the error by just delaying switching the mathcode, so change

```
    \mathcode`#1="8000
```

to

```
    \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }
```

But a more serious problem is that you are making every definition `{\color{abc}\olddefn}` which makes every character a mathord and destroys the spacing (just of `=` in this example as letters get mathord spacing anyway)  The following gets the math classof the original character and inserts `\mathxx` command into the definition so `=`  gets `\mathrel` and the correct spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,hyperref,color,xcolor}

\newcommand*{\mathcolor}{}
\def\mathcolor#1#{\mathcoloraux{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mathcoloraux}[3]{%
  \protect\leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \color#1{#2}#3%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\def\colorizemath #1#2{%
    \expandafter\mathchardef\csname orig:math:#1\endcsname\mathcode`#1
    \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }
    \toks@\expandafter{\csname orig:math:#1\endcsname}%
\count@\mathcode`#1 %
\divide\count@"1000 %
    \begingroup
       \lccode`~=`#1
       \lowercase{%
    \endgroup
       \edef~{%
  \ifcase\count@
    \or
    \mathop\or
    \mathbin\or
    \mathrel\or
    \mathopen\or
    \mathclose\or
    \mathpunct\or
  \fi
{\noexpand\color{#2}\the\toks@}}}%
   }
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{blue}}
\@for\@tempa:==\do{%
    \expandafter\colorizemath\@tempa{brown}}
\def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\color{black}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Test File}

\author{ABC}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The equation $1+1=2$ holds.

\end{document}
```