# How can I use color in a mathematical expression without losing horizontal spacing?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, color

How can I use color in a mathematical expression without losing horizontal spacing?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{dd0000}
\begin{document}
\[3+(-5)-2+3\]
\[3+(-5){\color{red}-2}+3\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: as egreg said you can use `\mathbin` or if you know the argument is a single character you can look up its existing type from its `\mathcode` and insert the appropriate `\mathxx` command automatically, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101699/how-to-escape-in-latexs-for-loop

Comment: Not really related [macros - How to color math symbols? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21598/how-to-color-math-symbols/261480#261480)  but the answers there also discuss the spacing issue (use mathcolor)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You lose the horizontal spacing because of the brace group `{}`. Besides egreg's solution there are two ways that don't require telling TeX the kind of object you want:

1. Use `\begingroup ... \endgroup` instead of `{...}`,
2. Use `\color{black}` to switch back to black.

Both yields the same result:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for gather
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{dd0000}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
3+(-5)-2+3 \\
3+(-5) \color{red} -2 \color{black} +3 \\
3+(-5)\begingroup\color{red}-2\endgroup+3
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to work a bit harder, telling TeX the kind of object you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{dd0000}
\begin{document}
\[3+(-5)-2+3\]
\[3+(-5)\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}}\textcolor{red}{2}+3\]
\end{document}
```

For a one shot application this is probably the easiest way. If the emphasis color is always the same, you could define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\mathem}[2][\mathord]{%
  #1{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}
```

and input the above as

```
3 + (-5) \mathem[\mathbin]{-} \mathem{2} + 3
```

[image]