# TIKZ/PGF: How to override the opacity of the text inside a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am trying to incrementally reveal one node at a time in a figure while preserving the text alignment across two nodes.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\newcommand{\x}{{\color{blue}\ensuremath{x}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
        \node[visible on=<1>] (b00) at (0, 0) {
            {\transparent{0}$3 \cdot ($}
            $f(\x)$
            {\transparent{0}$) + 5$}
            {$=$}
            {\transparent{0}$3 \cdot ($}
            $g(\x) * h(\x)$
            {\transparent{0}$) + 5$}
        };
        \node[visible on=<2>] (b00) at (0, 0) {
            {\transparent{0.5}$3 \cdot ($}
            $f(\x)$
            {\transparent{0.5}$) + 5$}
            {$=$}
            {\transparent{0.5}$3 \cdot ($}
            $g(\x) * h(\x)$
            {\transparent{0.5}$) + 5$}
        };
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to get:
f(x) = g(x) ∗ h(x) in the first slide and
3·(f(x)) + 5 = 3.(g(x)∗h(x)) + 5 in the second slide while preserving the alignment of f(x) = g(x) ∗ h(x) across both slides.

[image: Here is the desired result]

Is there a clean way to do this in TIKZ/PGF?

Comment: I guess you can consult the math spacing table (e.g. TeXbook page 170) and insert appropriate \math⟨type⟩ at appropriate places to get the correct spacing. there's an example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102254/how-can-i-use-color-in-a-mathematical-expression-without-losing-horizontal-spaci that one for color but the principle is about the same

Comment: you visible/invisible code doesn't work. Why don't you use simply `\node<1>` and `\node<2>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let beamer do the uncovering for you:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\x}{{\color{blue}\ensuremath{x}}}

\setbeamercovered{still covered={\opaqueness<1>{30}\opaqueness<2->{0}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<-2>
\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
        \node (b00) at (0, 0) {
          $
            \uncover<3->{3 \cdot (}
            f(\x)
            \uncover<3->{) + 5}
            =
            \uncover<3->{3 \cdot (}
            g(\x) * h(\x)
            \uncover<3->{) + 5}
          $
        };
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can simply color parts of the math. There is no need to seperate it that much. Use `begingroup` and `\endgroup` (like suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102300/47927) in order to keep the spacing correct even for binary operators (which is not a problem in your case, anyways).

I would suggest that you use the library `overlay-beamer-styles` for Ti*k*Z instead of providing your own `visible on` style. In the following code I added a slide without color to ehow that the spacing is correct.

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

%\newcommand{\x}{{\color{blue}\ensuremath{x}}}

\newcommand{\makeblue}[1]{\begingroup\color{blue}\ensuremath{#1}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\maketransparent}[2][0]{\begingroup\color{black!#1}\ensuremath{#2}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
        \node[visible on=<1>] (b00) at (0, 0) {
            $\maketransparent{3 \cdot (}
            f(\makeblue{x})
            \maketransparent{) + 5}
            =
            \maketransparent{3 \cdot (}
            g(\makeblue{x}) * h(\makeblue{x})
            \maketransparent{) + 5}$
        };
        \node[visible on=<2>] (b00) at (0, 0) {
            $\maketransparent[50]{3 \cdot (}
            f(\makeblue{x})
            \maketransparent[50]{) + 5}
            =
            \maketransparent[50]{3 \cdot (}
            g(\makeblue{x}) * h(\makeblue{x})
            \maketransparent[50]{) + 5}$
        };
        \node[visible on=<3>] (b00) at (0, 0) {
            $3 \cdot (f(x)) + 5 = 3 \cdot (g(x) * h(x)) + 5$
        };
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A more flexible command could be:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketransparent}{ O{0} O{black} m }{\begingroup\color{#2!#1}\ensuremath{#3}\endgroup}
```

It takes three arguments, two of which are optional and can be used to set the color and the opacity. The third argument takes the stuff that should be colored. A few examples:

```
\maketransparent{a}           % print an invisible a

\maketransparent[25]{a}       % print an a with 25 % opacity

\maketransparent[25][red]{a}  % print a red a with 25 % opacity
```

Comment: Is there a way to get `\maketransparent` working with all colors?
For instance, `\maketransparent{) \begingroup\color{red}+ 5\endgroup}` does not work.

Comment: @untitled No, you would need to adjust the macro for that. See my edit.