# Color symbols individually in math mode (unicode-math clash)

Tags: math-mode, color, unicode-math

The solution in the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100625 is highly efficient. Unfortunately it can not be used with unicode-math, which erases the individualized symbol colors. While unicode-math does allow individual symbol coloring via `\setmathfont`, if too many symbols are independently colored in this way, the source will not compile.

Is there any way to make the `\colorizemath` code (linked above) compatible with unicode-math ?

Comment: If you have an example that fails in unicode-math, please submit a bug in the issue tracker: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues . I'm not surprised you run into problems, but I might be able to develop an alternative interface if I can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: Honestly I cannot tell whether this is a bug, or an abuse of the package by yours truly. I have been using `\setmathfont` one glyph at a time to individualize colour etc. If `\setmathfont` is called more than a handful of times, the symbol font limit is exceeded; hence the source does not compile. If unicode-math wants to allow dozens of characters to be customized, one `\setmathfont` by one, I will happily submit a bug. **Unicode-math continues to be my favourite package**, with its prints all over documents like https://www.dropbox.com/s/m95ta9o6ac0l8wg/Project1Report_BenBarlow.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Nice example! Probably one glyph at a time is excessive, but I see you are using *lots* of difference colours :)

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet causes the variable *x* to display blue in math mode without affecting its appearance in text mode. Further, it seems to get along well with unicode-math. (This snippet can be extended to independently colour many symbols, and it compiles rapidly.)

```
\begingroup
\lccode`~=`x
\lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{{\color{blue}\symnormal{x}}}%
 }%
\mathcode`x="8000
```

(Code modified from https://texfaq.org/FAQ-activechars)

Answer (score 0):

The lcc lower-case-code method is a lookup.

An expl3 lookup method could be used.

Here, a token-list mapping function as proof-of-concept:

[image: maths in colour]

A key-value property-list could also be used in expl3, as an alternative.

Much patience needed, to set up *every* symbol (and operator).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagella-Math}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \sym_to_col:n #1
{
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { #1 }
        \str_case:VnTF 
            \l_tmpb_tl      
            {
                {  } { {\color{red}  } }
                { + } { {\color{green} + } }
                { m } { { {\colorbox{blue}{\color{yellow} $m$} } } }
                { n } { {\color{blue} n } }
                { ( } { {\color{brown} ( } }
                { ) } { {\color{brown} ) } }
                {  } { {\color{violet}  } }
            }
                 { }  % true
                    { #1 } % false
}


\NewDocumentCommand \colourmaths { m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \if_mode_math:
        \tl_map_function:NN 
                \l_tmpa_tl 
                \sym_to_col:n 
    \else:
            \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \fi:

}

\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_tmpa_prop
{
=blue,
}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

Text mode:

abc \colourmaths{mno} 

\bigskip
Math mode:

$xyz = \colourmaths{mn+qrs(0)}$

\end{document}
```