# overriding \everymath color: Is there an efficient way to apply color on every line for all arrays, and doing the same for cases as well?

Tags: math-mode, color, arrays, cases

TLDR; How does one efficiently apply color on every line of every array to override the color by `\everymath`? i.e from

[image]

to

[image]

(A compilable example of this is at the bottom)

Is there a way to efficiently apply `\color{black}` on every line for all arrays (rather than doing it line-by-line)?

---

I am a big fan of colors and I would like to color up all my inline maths to make the text more readable:

[image: e.g.]

But I would like the color for display maths to remain black.

After some googling, I found [Stefan's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37324/81426), which uses `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` from the `everysel` package. However, there is a known problem with `\everydisplay`: it does not work with some maths environments in `amsmath`. To get around it, he suggested redefining displayed math, and I found the following code snippet in [OP's comments to his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37319/how-do-i-get-different-colors-for-math-and-for-text#comment75083_37324):

```
\let\originaldisplaystyle\displaystyle \renewcommand\displaystyle{\color{black}\originaldisplaystyle}
\let\oldeq\equation \def\equation{\oldeq\color{black}}
```

So I tried using them with `\everymath`, and they are working pretty well, except that the colors in `array` & `cases` are not overridden, and I get something like this:
[image]

[image]

I tried redefining `cases` like this:

```
 \let\oldcase\cases \def\cases{\oldcase\color{black}}
```

but it only overrides the color of the first symbol:

[image]

Here is the latex for the equation above:

```
\begin{equation}\label{phi}
    \phi(\delta,w)=  
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if } \;  \quad  (a \in div_1 \land b \in div_2)  \Leftrightarrow div_1 = div_2 \\
    0 & \text{if } \;  \quad  (a \in div_1 \land b \in div_2)  \Leftrightarrow div_1 \not= div_2  \\
\end{cases} \text{ where }  \begin{aligned} \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l} \delta =\{div_1, div_2\} \\ w = \{a,b\}
\end{array} \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

On the other hand, I get `Error: Illegal Character in array tag` while trying to redefine array by `\let\olda\array \def\array{\olda\color{black}}`.

However, I am able to change one line of the array by putting `\color{black}` at the start of the line:

[image]

Is there a way to efficiently apply `\color{black}` on every line for all `array`s (rather than doing it line-by-line)? How do I do the same for `cases` as well?

---

Here is a compilable example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}                                      
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{E93F3C}

\usepackage{everysel}

\everymath{\color{myColor}}
\let\originaldisplaystyle\displaystyle \renewcommand\displaystyle{\color{black}\originaldisplaystyle}
\let\oldeq\equation \def\equation{\oldeq\color{black}}

\begin{document}


A  \textit{div point set} is any order-pair $(P,\Theta_P)$ satisfying
\begin{alignat}{2}
  \label{def1_1} 
  &\mathrlap{\lvert\Theta_P\rvert = \binom{\lvert P\rvert}{2} \land P \not= \varnothing} \\[1.5ex] 
  \label{def1_2}
  & \forall D_n \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l} \color{black}
  (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  \lvert d_n\rvert =2\\
  d_n \in \mathcal{P}(P)\\
  \lvert\delta_n\rvert = 2\\
  \bigcup \delta_n = P \setminus d_n \\
  \bigcap \delta_n = \varnothing
  \end{array}
  \end{aligned}\\[1.5ex]
  \label{def1_3}
    & \forall D_n, D_m \in \Theta_P & \quad & \begin{aligned}[t] \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l}
  (d_n,\delta_n) \mkern-2mu\coloneqq D_n \\
  (d_m,\delta_m) \coloneqq D_m\\
  d_n= d_m \Leftrightarrow D_n=D_m
  \end{array}
  \end{aligned}
\end{alignat}

\begin{equation}\label{phi}
    \phi(\delta,w)=  
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if } \;  \quad  (a \in div_1 \land b \in div_2)  \Leftrightarrow div_1 = div_2 \\
    0 & \text{if } \;  \quad  (a \in div_1 \land b \in div_2)  \Leftrightarrow div_1 \not= div_2  \\
\end{cases} \text{ where }  \begin{aligned} \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\begin{array}[t]{|@{\hskip0.6em}l} \delta =\{div_1, div_2\} \\ w = \{a,b\}
\end{array} \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A *complete* compilable example would be better.

Comment: @Manuel alright, I have updated my answer regarding that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that a compilable example is much better. You give a lot of information, but still, we can't compile anything to help you.

What about restoring `\everymath{}` any time you use in certain environment

```
\everymath{\color{red}} % May be it's more secure \everymath{\color{red}\everymath{}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alignat}{\everymath{}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\everymath{}}
% etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! You solution works pretty nicely! `\everymath{\color{red} \everymath{} }` would have red not to be applied to content in `array`, while  `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\everymath{}}` would have the red not to be applied to content in `equation`!