# How to define math enviroment $[math things]$ to be always colored some way?

Tags: math-mode, color

So, I was doing some math texting and I am one of those people that like to use color on texts;

So I was wondering if there is a way to make latex always color the in between $$ text to be of a certain color.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How put color in all math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211780/how-put-color-in-all-math-mode)

Comment: Other duplicates and related questions are https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48191/is-there-a-way-to-color-only-real-math-in-pdflatex https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64955/color-of-unicode-math-in-xetex https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268368/overriding-everymath-color-is-there-an-efficient-way-to-apply-color-on-every-l