# How to Globally Change Color of Matter Inside Inline and Displayed Math Mode?

Tags: math-mode, color, article

I want to change/redefine the math environment in `LaTeX` `Article` class such that whenever I write a mathematical expression `inline` or in `displayed math mode`, it appears in a color of my choice. Here is an example of what I mean:
[image] 
I can do it manually for every instance of `inline` math, or `displayed math` but I instead want to know how I can redefine the environment itself so that I have to do it only once and I can change the colors globally. Here is an MWE (in which I don't color the math):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Households save $a_{t} \geq 0$ in the riskless debt issued by 
experts with an interest rate $r_{t}$. Thus, wealth follows:
\begin{equation*} 
da_{t} = (w_{t}z_{t} + r_{t}a_{t} - c_{t})dt = s(a_{t}, z_{t}, K_{t}, G_{t})dt
\item Optimal choice: $c_{t} = c(a_{t}, z_{t}, K_{t}, G_{t})$
\end{equation*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{purple}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Households save $a_{t} \geq 0$ in the riskless debt issued by 
experts with an interest rate $r_{t}$. Thus, wealth follows:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}a_{t} = (w_{t}z_{t} + r_{t}a_{t} - c_{t})\,\mathrm{d}t 
= s(a_{t}, z_{t}, K_{t}, G_{t})\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
\item Optimal choice: $c_{t} = c(a_{t}, z_{t}, K_{t}, G_{t})$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that there can be all sorts of issues, see e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11834) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37324). Naively one may think to use `\everydisplay`, too, but there are some drawbacks. At least with inline math and `align` this proposal works. Please note also that you cannot have an `\item` in an equation.

Comment: Always my best compliments for your fast answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for `\[\]` or `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` though.