# Create a command for inline math, and apply color to math output

Tags: math-mode, inline

I would like to setup a command for adding inline math in text paragraphs. In that command, I want to change some style properties, like change the color of the equation. Fox example:

```
The value of $x = 2 + 3$ is $x=5$.
```

I would like to do.

```
 The value of \Mimath{x = 2 + 3} is \Mimath{x=5}.
```

I through I could start with something like this:

```
\newcommand*\Mimath[1]{ $ #1 $ }
```

But that gives an error in TexStudio:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...lection of objects whatsoever. A set \Mimath
```

How can I create that type of command?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, I hope for you too:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\Mimath[2][black]{{\color{#1} $ #2 $}\color{black} }

\begin{document}
The value of    \Mimath[red]{y=x+5}

The value of    \Mimath[blue]{y=x+5}

The value of    \Mimath[magenta]{y=x+5}

The value of    \Mimath{y=x+5}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: +1. I don't think that `\color{black}` is needed, though.

Comment: I'd use: `\newcommand*\Mimath[2][black]{$\color{#1}#2$}`.

Comment: @Mico without \color{black} does not reset the color of text to black and continues the same color of math mode

Comment: Sorry, I should have written either `\newcommand*\Mimath[2][black]{$\color{#1}#2$}` or `\newcommand*\Mimath[2][black]{{\color{#1}$#2$}}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\everymath{\color{blue}}`. Here is a [minimimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\begin{document}

The value of $x = 2 + 3$ is $x=5$.

\[
   \int2x\,dx=x^2+C
\]

\end{document}
```

that produces:

[image]

As the MWE shows, this colours only inline mathematics. If you want to colour displayed equations as well use `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}`.

Comment: Running `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}` can cause unexpected results, to put it mildly. Running `\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\color{blue}}` is safer.

Comment: @Mico Really? I have not come across this. Is there a reference about this that I can look at or some examples?

Comment: The issue is that `\everydisplay{\color{blue}}` clobbers any preexisting token list, which may have been set up by some package the user has loaded. For a practical example of what can go wrong see, e.g., [Modifying \everydisplay causes the align* environment to stop working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11778/5001).