# Reducing font size in equation

Tags: equations, fontsize

I wanted to type an equation in LaTeX. But it is too long to fit into one line. It involves big arrays with many columns so I cannot split it. I wanted to reduce the font size so that it can fit in one line. However, `\small` doesn't work in the `equation` environment.

Comment: Can we see the actual equation? Perhaps we could then suggest some alternatives.

Comment: as a last resort, just pack the whole thing into a `\scalebox` and shrink as much as necessary.  rewriting as much as possible would be advisable first.

Comment: I agree with Gonzalo, don't scale unless nothing else can be done. If the equation is so large that scaling is needed, chances are that scaling the equation will not make it be more understandable for the reader. In most cases a rewrite is a better option.

Answer (score 158):

The following illustrates font size alterations in mathmode:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}               % Necessary to use \scalebox
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\noindent 
normal: $ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $\\
displaystyle: $ {\displaystyle x^2 + 2xy + y^2} $\\
scriptstyle: $ {\scriptstyle x^2 + 2xy + y^2} $\\
scriptscriptstyle: $ {\scriptscriptstyle x^2 + 2xy + y^2} $\\
textstyle: $ {\textstyle x^2 + 2xy + y^2} $

\noindent
\scalebox{0.5}{%
normal: $ x^2 + 2xy + y^2$}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Note that:

- `\displaystyle` gives the command to switch the math font size to
  normal size for displayed formulas.
- `\textstyle` is used to go back to normal size font for inline formulas.
- `\scriptstyle` is used to set the math font to a size used for subscripted and superscripted symbols.
- `\scriptscriptstyle` provides the normal size for doubly
  subscripted and superscripted symbols.

When using the `\scalebox` command from the `graphicx` package one can specify the width (or height) and the other dimension will be scaled proportionally. In a similar manner you can specify both dimensions, but in this case it is all about aesthetics. Therefore we have the following under the `\scalebox` command:

- `\scalebox{h-dimension}{v-dimension}{content to be scaled}`: both dimension stated.
- `\scalebox{h-dimension}{content}`: both arguments (`h-dim` and `v-dim`) scaled with respect to the stated dimension.

Comment: $\scriptstyle$ etc. not only changes the font size. It also affects how lines are broken.

Comment: When you use fractions within display math mode, the font size is automatically reduced... ...to what size?

Comment: The command `\scriptstyle` worked so well, it can be applied to only part of the equation and it only decrease the font size, doing nothing else. Thanks!

Comment: somehow `\scriptstyle` reduces the font of only the first symbol following it inside an `align`, is that behavior expected?

Comment: @xealits Without the code I cannot say what is the issue.

Comment: @xealits Yes it is the expected behavior: each & or \\ require a new size

Comment: @ErnestoIglesias Any way to make `\scriptystyle` holds for an entire `align` environment instead of only for one side of an `=` side for example?

Answer (score 81):

Just put `\small` *before* the equation and `\normalsize` after it if you want to shrink the font, but it's usually better to use an ams multi-line equation environment than to change font size.

It's actually easier to only do the part of a size change command that affects math without changing the baseline to avoid the problems @barabara-beeton mentions. This is a `\tiny` (5pt) equation in a `\large` paragraph text, to highlight the differences, and to show that the above and below display skips are not altered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth3

\begin{document}
\large

hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
$$abc+xyz=44$$
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 

hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5}\check@mathfonts
$$abc+xyz=44$$\endgroup
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 


\end{document}
```

---

with AMS `align` this would produce:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth3

\begin{document}
\large

hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
\begin{align}
abc&+xyz&&=44\\
x&-y&&=2\\
a&+b&&=77
\end{align}
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 

hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga hghghga 
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5}\check@mathfonts
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\large\normalfont#1}}%
\begin{align}
abc&+xyz&&=44\\
x&-y&&=2\\
a&+b&&=77
\end{align}\endgroup
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 
bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb bbbbbb 


\end{document}
```

Comment: however, unless there's a paragraph break before the display, the baselines of the preceding paragraph will be fouled up, and if there *is* a blank line/pargraph break before the display, the vertical space preceding the display will be fouled up, and a page break would also be allowed because of the paragraph break.  there's no good (automatic) mechanism defined for this yes, as far as i know.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes I was going to mention that. If there were a MWE I'd have probably shown it with a correction for baselinskip. I suppose I should make one. It can't be that hard can it to insert a par while preserving the predispolay skip.

Comment: @barbarabeeton something like the code in the updated answer?

Comment: make it a 3-line display and i'll be happier.

Comment: @barbarabeeton 3 line display added, so you should be happy, but I guess you wanted tighter line spacing in the display?

Comment: yes, i'm happier now -- all the ramifications are visible.  thank you.  and yes, for the smallified display, i see two things that bother me (actually three, but i'll ignore the unaligned = signs).  you've identified the first (the vertical spacing), but what's done there depends on the second: the equation numbers shouldn't change size.  (we've got a fix for that, already in place in-house.  too complicated to show the code in a comment.)  this problem is on our list, but we haven't yet found a foolproof solution, and will keep looking for ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3831/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-barbara-beeton)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Adding `\small` before the equation doesn't work unless you precede with a `\par` (otherwise it shrinks the preceding paragraph's line spacing)… but I just learned from you in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337104/where-does-the-space-before-align-come-from that it was wrong to add that `\par`… so how do you actually change the size (including the tighter line spacing in the math itself)?

Comment: @Clément with difficulty:-) best to ask that as a new question I think, also depends whether you need to allow page breaking (as that stops some simplifications like doing the small text inside a parbox)

Comment: @Clément `\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textwidth{7cm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\Large\sloppy

\def\aa{one two three four five six seven eight }
\def\bb{\aa blue black red \aa\aa yellow pink black orange \aa}

\bb\aa
\begin{align}
a+b+c &=1=2+3 \\
b+c &= z\\
c&=5
\end{align}
\bb\aa
%
\everydisplay{\fontsize{7pt}{10pt}\selectfont}%
%
\aa
\begin{align}
a+b+c &=1=2+3 \\
b+c &= z\\
c&=5
\end{align}
\bb


\end{document}`

Comment: I always find Your solution simple and efficient. Really grateful to You

Answer (score 36):

Similar to [How to make math font huge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31416/how-to-make-math-font-huge/31417#31417), you can use `\scalebox` to scale down the equation, or `\resizebox` the box to a specific width to reduce the size.
The first is the normal display mode equation, followed by the scaled version with `\scalebox` and `\resizebox`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\begin{document}
\[y = \sin^2 x\]
%
\[\Scale[0.5]{y = \sin^2 x}\]
%
\[ \Resize{1cm}{y = \sin^2 x}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Best solution among others

Answer (score 17):

If you want to change the size in the middle of an equation, you can try to change to text mode, change the size, an them retype in equation mode using $$.

Example:

```
\begin{equation}
A + B = \text{\footnotesize $C + D$} + E
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: on mathJax one can do $A+B = {\tiny C+ D} + E$

Answer (score 11):

Why nobody mentions the `small` environment?

```
\begin{small}
\[ x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \]
\end{small}
```

Comment: Because it isn't an environment, it just works because, well. It just does, the internals never test, if `\endsmall` is def'ed.

Comment: @Johannes_B Not really:better to say the implementation of environments is explicitly coded to work whether or not the end code is defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, feature, no bug?

Comment: Your `small` environment knows to behave in a very strange way, and should not be used. It is a (questionable) design choice that the `\small` command defined the `small` environment as well. Notice that you can use `\begin{cite}{article123}\end{cite}` instead of `\cite{article123}` and the effect will be almost the same, just it will have some strange consequences.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes (although has to be used with care, tricky to get white space correct when doing this, with any environment not just `small`)

Comment: Nobody mentioned it because it's wrong: see [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h3zRd.png) for knowing why. I used `footnotesize` for making the effect more evident, but it's noticeable also with `small`.

Comment: @egreg I could not see what's wrong...

Comment: @TonyBetaLambda Did you look at the interline spacing *above* the equation?

Comment: @egreg Okay, I see.

Answer (score 8):

First, put the following code in the preamble:

```
\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}
```

Then you can change the size of your equation using `\scalemath` as follows:

```
$$\scalemath{2}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
$$\scalemath{1}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
$$\scalemath{0.8}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
$$\scalemath{0.6}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
$$\scalemath{0.4}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
$$\scalemath{0.2}{sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2}$$
\[
\scalemath{0.7}{
sin(x)^2 + cos(x) + x^2
}
\]
```

[image]