# Adjusting font size with TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, nodes

Taking from the PGF manual,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \coordinate (a) at (rnd,rnd);
  \coordinate (b) at (3-rnd,3-rnd);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
  \node (c) at (1,2) {x};
  \draw let \p1 = ($ (a)!(c)!(b) - (c) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to increase the size of `x`. The problem is that I have multiple circles in the same diagram. Some of them require a larger sized font, while others are okay at default. How do I do this?

Comment: how about `\node[scale=3] at (1,2) {x}` (choose the number appropriately)

Comment: @cmhughes: why not post an answere? `;)`

Comment: What are the necessary `\usetikzlibrary{}` items for this picture to work? `positioning` for sure, but how to get rid of `Undefined control sequence         in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1]`?

Answer (score 249, accepted):

You can change the font size inside a tikZ node like you do it in normal LaTeX – use one of these:

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

e.g.

```
\node (c) at (1,2) {\large x};
```

or

```
\node (c) at (1,2) {\large $x$}; %note the \large *outside* the inline math
```

**Edit:**
To change font size **inside** math mode, LaTeX provides the following commands:

```
\displaystyle
\textstyle
\scriptstyle
\scriptscriptstyle
```

Using scaling algorithms provided by tikZ/pgf (e.g. `scale=...`) scales "the entire character", so it may look ugly if you use too much scaling. If you set the font sizes with the above commands, LaTeX selects different symbols for the different font sizes. This ensures the fonts are readable and have enough "details". If you want a more extreme scaling, use the `scale=3.0` option for the node.

Comment: it says it's invalid with math mode?

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out the `font` key which could be of help in this case `:)`

Comment: @ralfix sorry i didn't mention it. it's too early in the morning for me. bah!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Do you mean the `scale` option?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: you're right... what I wanted to say was that `\node (c) at (1,2) {\large x};` is equivalent to `\node[font=\large] (c) at (1,2) {x};`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: with the notable exception that `{\large x\\y}` produces a large `x` and a normal `y`, while `\node[font=\large,align=center] {x\\y}` makes everything large.

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation) for discussion on scaling **inside** math mode

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I would like to note that for multi-line text there is a difference between `\node at (...) [font=\small, text width=1cm]{A long text ...};` and `\node at (...) [text width=1cm] {\small A long text ...};` regarding the line spacing. In the first case, the line spacing is adjusted, in the second it is not. The line break is also different.

Comment: @Michael.H: Absolutely right, and the same applies to Michaël's observation. Indeed my example was with one character only and does not generalize to something more complex.

Answer (score 58):

Set a new style so that you can use it later.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{relsize}

\tikzset{fontscale/.style = {font=\relsize{#1}}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \coordinate (a) at (rnd,rnd);
  \coordinate (b) at (3-rnd,3-rnd);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
  \node (c) at (1,2) [fontscale=4] {x};
  \draw let \p1 = ($ (a)!(c)!(b) - (c) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27):

At the top, write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1.3}]
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
\coordinate (a) at (rnd,rnd);
\coordinate (b) at (3-rnd,3-rnd);
\draw (a) -- (b);
\node (c) at (1,2) {x};
\draw let \p1 = ($ (a)!(c)!(b) - (c) $),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
    in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the thick changes your arrows, the first scale changes the scale of your drawing, but the second argument changes the size of your nodes, presumably where you have your text.  This will change for all nodes.

Comment: This wont work for this example actually.  It will change the font size for all labels however.

Comment: This method solved a problem that had been bothering me for years, as I needed to scale the figure, and resize the font accordingly.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `font` option of the `\node` command. The `font` option accepts typical font commands such as `\node[font = {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}, red]` (huge font size, bold, sans serif).

> [image]

*(Taken from the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).)*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \coordinate (a) at (rnd,rnd);
  \coordinate (b) at (3-rnd,3-rnd);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
  \node[font = {\normalfont}, red] (c) at (1,2) {x}; % <=== See here!
  \draw let \p1 = ($ (a)!(c)!(b) - (c) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,3);
  \coordinate (a) at (rnd,rnd);
  \coordinate (b) at (3-rnd,3-rnd);
  \draw (a) -- (b);
  \node[font = {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}, red] (c) at (1,2) {x}; % <=== See here!
  \draw let \p1 = ($ (a)!(c)!(b) - (c) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in circle [at=(c), radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize 
\large
\Large  
\LARGE  
\huge   
\Huge
```

> [image]

*(Taken from the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).)*