# Formatting a Block Matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to typeset the matrix depicted in the diagram, I've considered many examples, and in particular [easybmat](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat?lang=en). But nothing came closer than the approach I settled on given below. However it does not quite produce the accuracy I wanted. Is there a way to make the diagram closer to the required picture?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{easybmat}

\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\Huge0}}}
\begin{document} 

\[
\sbox0{$\begin{array}{c c c |}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\\ \hline\end{array}$}
\sbox1{$\begin{array}{| r|}\hline \\ 2\\ \hline\end{array}$}
\sbox2{$\begin{matrix}2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{matrix}$}
\sbox3{$\begin{array}{c c c |}2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\\ \hline\end{array}$}
%
A=\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\usebox{0}&  & \bigzero & \\
& \usebox{1} &  & \\
\bigzero & & \usebox{3} & \\
& &  & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Required Picture]
[image: Gotten so far]

Comment: Rather than posting images it is better to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For questions like this a `matrix of math nodes` is your friend. These are [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) matrix that allow you to draw lines connecting the matrix entries.

Here the output I get:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\[ A =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                      large/.style={font=\large}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
                column sep={1.2em,between origins},
                row sep={1.2em,between origins}
    ]{ 0 & 1 & 0 &   &              \\
       0 & 0 & 1 &   &   &   &   &  \\
       0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &          \\
         &   &   & 2 &   &          \\
         &   &   &   & 2 & 1 & 0 &  \\
         &   &   &   & 0 & 2 & 1 &  \\
         &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 2 &  \\
         &   &   &   &   &   &   & 0\\
     };
    \draw(M-3-1.south west)--([xshift=2mm]M-3-4.south east);
    \draw(M-4-3.south)--(M-4-4.south east);
    \draw(M-7-5.south)--([xshift=2mm]M-7-7.south);
    \draw(M-1-3.north east)--(M-4-4.south west);
    \draw(M-4-4.north east)--(M-5-5.south west);
    \draw(M-5-7.north east)--(M-7-7.south east);
    \node[large] at (M-2-7){$0$};
    \node[large] at (M-7-2){$0$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Some words of explanation:

- The `(M)` after `\matrix` means that the nodes have labels `(M-1-1)`, `(M-1-2)` etc. You can change `(M)` to anything you like.
- The node `(M-3-1.south west)` is the south west corner of the entry in row 3 and column 1. Simiarly, there are `north`, `east`, `south`, ...
- I have used a `matrix of math nodes` but there is also a `matrix of nodes`. The difference, as you'd suspect, is that `matrix of math nodes` puts the matrix entries into math-mode.
- the `nodes in empty cells` creates labels for empty cells.
- I didn't put the large `0`s into the matrix because this would have warped the row and column sizes
- The lines `column sep={1.2em,between origins}` and `row sep={1.2em,between origins}` makes the distances between the center of the rows and columns the same, which you want if you are drawing vertical and horizontal lines between the matrix entries
- you need to put braces around the delimiters in `left delimiter={[}` and `right delimiter={]}`
- the `baseline=(current bounding box.center)` is there to center the matrix in the displayed equation
- the `large/.style={font=\large}` sets the font size for the "large" zeros in the matrix (this is the meaning of the `large` in `\node[large]`).

Comment: Thx! I was going to use Tikz as a last resort ;) Now I know this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

100% based on [Andrew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30471/andrew)'s answer, I'm simply providing a possible solution to the 'large zero problem', based on the answer to [Adjusting font size with TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107057/adjusting-font-size-with-tikz-picture)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\[ A =
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center),
                  large/.style={font=\large}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
            left delimiter={[}, right delimiter={]},
            column sep={1.2em,between origins},
            row sep={1.2em,between origins}
    ]{ 0 & 1 & 0 &   &              \\
       0 & 0 & 1 &   &   &   &   &  \\
       0 & 0 & 0 &   &   &          \\
         &   &   & 2 &   &          \\
         &   &   &   & 2 & 1 & 0 &  \\
         &   &   &   & 0 & 2 & 1 &  \\
         &   &   &   & 0 & 0 & 2 &  \\
         &   &   &   &   &   &   & 0\\
     };
    \draw(M-3-1.south west)--([xshift=2mm]M-3-4.south east);
    \draw([xshift=1mm]M-4-3.south)--([xshift=1mm]M-4-4.south east);
    \draw(M-7-5.south)--([xshift=3mm]M-7-7.south);
    \draw(M-1-3.north east)--(M-4-4.south west);
    \draw(M-4-4.north east)--(M-5-5.south west);
    \draw(M-5-7.north east)--([yshift=-1mm]M-7-7.south east);
    \node[] at (M-2-7){\Huge 0};
    \node[] at (M-7-2){\Huge 0};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: LargeZeroSolution]

Comment: In my answer I used `\large`. If you want a bigger 0 then all that you need to do is change the `large/.style={font=\large}` in my post to `large/.style={font=\Huge}`.  (See my last dot-point:)