# circuitikz: Change the scale of a label

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to be able to highlight the text of a label of a component for example by increasing the size of the text.
How can I do ?
Thank you

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. It would be helpful if you elaborate, ideally provide an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Comment: Potential duplicate or at least related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107057/

Comment: Do the provided answer answer your question? If yes (or no), please leave feedback and / or accept an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the Ti*k*Z settings [shown by @FHZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/637020/38080), you can either simply use the font commands in the label, if it's a one-off thing, like:

```
to[R, l={\LARGE $R$}]
```

or you can set label and annotation styles globally, as shown in [the manual in section 5.6](https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsection.5.6), using `bipole label style`.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
Specific label font (just the second one):

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) to[R, l=$R$] ++(2,0) to[R, l={\LARGE $R$}] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

Setting label font (for every label from now on, or in scope)

\ctikzset{bipole label style/.style={font=\LARGE}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) to[R, l=$R$] ++(2,0) to[R, l=$R$] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best I can do without a specific example is to present a few examples of how to interact with `scale`, `font` for a specific `node`/`draw` or to a set of them inside a `scope`. The same methodology also applies to colors.

Between `scale` and `font`, `font` is the option to increase only the size of fonts. Avoid `scale` if you don't intend to also increase the components design itself.

A MWE follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\begin{scope}
  \draw (0,0) to[R,o-o,l=$R$,f=$i_R$,v<=$v_R$,color=blue] ++(0,-2);
  
  \draw[scale=1.3] (0,0.5) node{$v_R(t) = R i_R(t)$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}, purple,
  every node/.style={scale=1.5}]
  \draw (0,0) to[R,o-o,l=$R$,f=$i_R$,v<=$v_R$,color=blue] ++(0,-2);
  
  \draw (0,0.5) node{$v_R(t) = R i_R(t)$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)}]
  \draw (0,0) to[C,*-*,l=$C$,f=$i_C$,v<=$v_C$,color=red] ++(0,-2);
  
  \draw[font = {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}, cyan] (3,0) 
  to[L,*-*,l=$L$,f=$i_L$,v<=$v_L$] ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[shift={(12,0)}, font = {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}, magenta]
  \draw (0,0) to[C,*-*,l=$C$,f=$i_C$,v<=$v_C$,color=red] ++(0,-2);
  
  \draw (3,0) 
  to[L,*-*,l=$L$,f=$i_L$,v<=$v_L$] ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]