# Modify the size of a text in a tikz picture with a triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Searching several posts in tex.stackechange I have created the figure below using the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
my angle/.style = {draw, fill=black!20,
                   angle radius=7mm, 
                   angle eccentricity=1.1, 
                   right, inner sep=1pt,
                   font=\footnotesize} 
                   ]             
\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above,rotate=33.7,font=\footnotesize] {$D=\sqrt{x_0^2+\left(\frac{v_0}{\omega_0}\right)^2}$} (B) -- node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$\frac{v_0}{\omega_0}$} (C) -- node[below,font=\footnotesize] {$x_0$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\pic[my angle, "$\phi$"] {angle = C--A--B};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I modify the textsize of the vertices A, B and C? It seems to me just adding `font=\footnotesize` (that is, e.g., `\coordinate [label=left:$C$,font=\footnotesize] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);` is not the proper way.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107058/197451

Comment: `label={[font=\footnotesize]left:$C$}` Your way just changed the font size of the `coordinate` (which doesn't have text). There's also the `every label` style. You can use any other style between `[` and `]` that at some point sets the `font` key (or the `node font` key) – just like you did with `my angle`.

Comment: See also `every node/.style={...}` (page 226).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
    quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        my angle/.style = {draw, fill=black!20,
            angle radius=7mm, 
            angle eccentricity=1.1, 
            right, inner sep=1pt,
            font=\footnotesize} 
        ]             
        \coordinate [label=left:\footnotesize $C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
        \coordinate [label=right:\footnotesize $A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
        \coordinate [label=above:\footnotesize $B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
        \draw (A) -- node[above,rotate=33.7,font=\footnotesize] {$D=\sqrt{x_0^2+\left(\frac{v_0}{\omega_0}\right)^2}$} (B) -- node[right,font=\footnotesize] {$\frac{v_0}{\omega_0}$} (C) -- node[below,font=\footnotesize] {$x_0$} (A);
        
        \draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
        
        \pic[my angle, "$\phi$"] {angle = C--A--B};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```