# Problem with long limits in \lim command

Tags: math-mode

When I write a long limit there is a big gap between the limit and the function. How can I fix this? Furthermore is there a way to make the limits smaller so as not to be longer than the limit symbol? Also why is that gap there and that size difference between the length of the symbol and the limit under it? Shouldn't all be under it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty}x(n)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That question doesn't answer mine. Just a fraction of it.

Comment: Does [Peter's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170662/5764) answer your question? I would discourage fiddling with the size of the subscript...

Comment: ...you could try `\scripscriptstyle`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package. Altough I would not recommend it, you can resize the subscript via the solutions from [Reducing font size in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation/):

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation/
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
Without \verb|\mathclap|:
\[  \lim_{n\to +\infty}x(n) \]
But with \verb|\mathclap|::
\[ \lim_{\mathclap{n \to +\infty}}x(n) \]
Using \verb|\scriptstyle| to resize:
\[ \lim_{\scriptscriptstyle n \to +\infty} x(n) \]
Using \verb|\Scale|
\[ \lim_{\Scale[0.5]{n \to +\infty}} x(n) \]
Using \verb|\Resize|
\[ \lim_{\Resize{\widthof{$\lim{}$}}{n \to +\infty}} x(n) \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very helpful! Is it possible to make the limits to start at the beggining of the lim symbol and not ahead of it? I mean not to be centered the lim symbol and the limits.

Comment: @Adam: I don't know how to do that, but I think that should be a separate question.