# Question about limits in lim command and scale in mathtools package

Tags: positioning, math-operators

This is a follow up question regarding the limits in `\lim` command and `mathtools` package. To begin with how can I make the limits to start at the beggining of the lim symbol and not ahead of it? Meaning the lim symbol and the limits not to be centered.

[image]

Also in the mathtool package if I use the scale option then the limits are scaled but as it seems to me around a point and so as the scale becomes smaller the larger the vertical gap between the limits and the lim symbol becomes. How can I fix that so that the vertical space will remail the same as the original in the lim command? And why is that happening?

[image]

This is a the code I used to try some cases, which belongs to Peter Grill who posted it to answer a previous question of mine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation/
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\begin{document}
\noindent
Without \verb|\mathclap|:
\[  \lim_{n\to +\infty}x(n) \]
But with \verb|\mathclap|::
\[ \lim_{\mathclap{n \to +\infty}}x(n) \]
Using \verb|\scriptstyle| to resize:
\[ \lim_{\scriptscriptstyle n \to +\infty} x(n) \]
Using \verb|\Scale|
\[ \lim_{\Scale[0.5]{n \to +\infty}} x(n) \]
Using \verb|\Resize|
\[ \lim_{\Resize{\widthof{$\lim{}$}}{n \to +\infty}} x(n) \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacks make this very easy.  The alignment is set with a mode parameter (`\stackalignment`), the gap is set with an optional stacking argument.  The use of `\useanchorwidth` says to not allow the width of the underset to affect the spacing to the next item.  EDITED to use `\mathop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathop{\stackunder[3pt]{\lim}{\scriptstyle n\rightarrow+\infty}} x(n)
\]
\[
\mathop{\stackunder[2.5pt]{\lim}{\scriptscriptstyle n\rightarrow+\infty}} x(n)
\]
\[
\mathop{\stackunder[2pt]{\lim}{\scalebox{.33}{$n\rightarrow+\infty$}}} x(n)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `\usearchorwidth` had been defined as `{F}` instead of `{T}`, the result would look like

[image]

---

The alignment and anchorwidth parameters can be directly incorporated into the syntax, which has the further advantage of making their invocation impervious to the current mode settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\mathop{\stackengine{3pt}{\lim}{\scriptstyle n\rightarrow+\infty}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}} x(n)
\]
\[
\mathop{\stackengine{2.5pt}{\lim}{\scriptscriptstyle n\rightarrow+\infty}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}} x(n)
\]
\[
\mathop{\stackengine{2pt}{\lim}{\scalebox{.33}{$n\rightarrow+\infty$}}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}} x(n)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean that I can change the vertical gap?

Comment: @Adam  The optional argument to `\stackunder` and/or the first argument to `\stackengine` (the alternative form at the end of my answer) are the gaps between the stacked items.  See the stackengine package documentation (http://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine) for a discussion of what "gap" means for so-called short vs. long stacks.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\mathrel`???

Comment: @egreg `\mathop` seemed too small, but I guess I shouldn't break the rules.

Comment: @Adam Just thought you should know that I updated the accepted answer to use `\mathop` rather than `\mathrel` after egreg correctly questioned my initial choice.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work in subscripts or superscripts (it might be made so):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\awfullim}{\@ifnextchar_{\@awfullim}{\lim}}
\newcommand{\@awfullim}[2]{% #1 is _
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$\lim$}%
  \settowidth{\dimen2}{$\scriptstyle#2$}%
  \ifdim\dimen2<\dimen0
    \lim_{#2}%
  \else
    \addtolength{\dimen2}{-\dimen0}%
    \kern-\dimen2 \lim_{\kern\dimen2 #2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\awfullim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\awfullim_{y\to+\infty}f(1/y)
\]
\end{document}
```

The name I used tells you how much I like this idea. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: Can I use it with mathclap so there is no space between the `\lim` command and the function? Also what do you mean about the subscripts and superscripts?

Comment: @Adam This is already horrible; removing the space above the limits is abhominable. ;-)

Comment: I agree but can be done?

Comment: @Adam Just use `\lim_{\mathmakebox[\dimen0][l]{\kern\dimen2 #2}}`