# Change spacing under \lim

Tags: spacing

I would like to increase the spacing of the lower limit of `\lim` command, such as:
[image]
The default (first) does not have enough space between the $x$ and the $c$, the second is what I would like it to look like, currently I use the space `\;` command to put this space in, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX doesn't space relation symbols when in subscripts or superscripts.

You can modify the behavior for the case at hand by making TeX into thinking that it's typesetting text style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\lim}{e{_}}{%
  \qopname\relax m{lim}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\text{\m@th\thickmuskip=3mu $#1$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\lim_{x\to c} f(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

The standard value of `\thickmuskip` is 5mu, which seems too much here, so I locally reduce it to 3mu. Make experiments to see what's the best for you.

[image]

The strange concoction `\qopname\relax m{lim}` is how `\lim` is defined by `amsmath`.

A way to do several operators at once can be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\changebigoperators}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \appto { ##1 } { \addspacelimits }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\addspacelimits}{e{_^}}
 {%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{\wrap{#1}}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{^{\wrap{#2}}}%
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrap}{m}
 {%
  \text{\mathsurround=0pt\thickmuskip=3mu$#1$}%
 }

\changebigoperators{sum,prod,lim}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\dots\prod_{k=1}^n \\
\lim_{x\to c}f(x)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can this be extended to sums and products, for example? How would I change the limits on \sum?

Comment: @bshepard I added a general way.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is probably the best.
The rationale is this

`\lim{constraint} F(x)`

The constraint is not parameterized by `\lim`  It's your constraint, so it would be overwhelming for `\lim` to have assumptions built in that there's a variable then a symbol then another argument, etc..

Eg., if there was a variant of `\lim`,  maybe `\roomylim` that worked as:

```
% Making this up...
\roomylimitspacer{\;}
% ...
\roomylim{x}{\to}{0} F(x)
```

Then it would be conceivable that the new macro could entertain settings to nudge `x` and `0` apart from the separator.  But, I don't recall seeing a variant of `\lim` like that.

If you find that you're making repeated use of this idiom, then a `\newcommand` might be order for your document that embeds the roomy-separator.

I go with "LaTeX usually knows what to do, and when it doens't, then there's a fix." like the one you're thinking `\;` (if that's your preference for tiny bit of horizontal space, so be it.)

I found this related article.

[Question about limits in lim command and scale in mathtools package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171509/question-about-limits-in-lim-command-and-scale-in-mathtools-package)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is here:
[Arrows of arbitrary length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269935/arrows-of-arbitrary-length)

In fact if you consider the code given by AboAmmar you get:

[image]

```
\lim_{x\,\Arrow{.2cm}\,c}f(x)\qquad\lim_{x\,\Arrow{.4cm}\,c}f(x)
```