# What is the meaning of the "at mark" @, also called "Klammeraffe", in LaTeX commands?

Tags: macros, symbols

I have seen the "at symbol" on several occasions, used in connection with LaTeX macros,
often as part of command names. Does this symbol have a special significance in LaTeX, or is it just a convenient special convention?

An example I found at this site is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation), like this :

```
begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5}\check@mathfonts
$$abc+xyz=44$$\endgroup
```

If the question has been asked before, a hint or a pointer will be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Tank you!  I followed your link and found 4 good answers. What do we do now, should I remove the question – since it already exists – or should it be left as a kind of road-sign?

Comment: Leave it as a road sign (nice analogy, BTW) `:)`