# Reducing font in equation in slide

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize

I review some related questions:
[Reducing font size in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation)

But it seems that cannot work in my case (in slide).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{$\mathcal{A}_d$ and $\mathcal{A}_d^*$}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\mathcal{A}_d: \mathcal{S}^4 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{3\times 3}$  


\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{A}(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} Z_{11}-Z_{22}-Z_{33}+Z_{44} & 2Z_{12}+2Z_
{34} & 2Z_{13}-2Z_{24} \\ 2Z_{12}-2Z_{34} & -Z_{11}+Z_{22}-Z_{33}+Z_{44}&      
2Z_{23}+2Z_{14} \\ 2Z_{13}+2Z_{24} & 2Z_{23}-2Z_{14}  & -Z_{11}-Z_{22}+Z_{33}+Z_{44}  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\item $\mathcal{A}_d^*: \mathbf{R}^{3\times 3} \rightarrow  \mathcal{S}^4  $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It shows (it should be a 4 by 4 matrix.)

[image]

> How could I choose the size of font in the equation such that all elements of matrix show up?  (only for this case not for all slides)

Comment: please omit the blank line before the `equation*}, or place a `%` in that line to make it "invisible" to latex.  a blank line before any display always results in too much space before the display.  in the present case, it makes it look like the display is associated with what comes below it instead of with the preceding line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `{\tiny ... }` before your aligned environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default} 
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
   \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{$\mathcal{A}_d$ and $\mathcal{A}_d^*$}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\mathcal{A}_d: \mathcal{S}^4 \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{3\times 3}$  


\begin{equation*}
{\tiny  
  \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{6pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{\abovedisplayskip}
  \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{3pt}
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{A}(Z) = \begin{bmatrix} Z_{11}-Z_{22}-Z_{33}+Z_{44} & 2Z_{12}+2Z_
{34} & 2Z_{13}-2Z_{24} \\ 2Z_{12}-2Z_{34} & -Z_{11}+Z_{22}-Z_{33}+Z_{44}&      
2Z_{23}+2Z_{14} \\ 2Z_{13}+2Z_{24} & 2Z_{23}-2Z_{14}  & -Z_{11}-Z_{22}+Z_{33}+Z_{44}  
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
}
\end{equation*}

\item $\mathcal{A}_d^*: \mathbf{R}^{3\times 3} \rightarrow  \mathcal{S}^4  $
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]