# Patch starred environment and use it as nested environment in a new environment

Tags: environments, starred-version, patching

For every (most?) environment `\begin{X}...\end{X}` there exists the macros `\X` and `\endX` that can be used inside the `\newenvironment` command. I.e, one can write something like this

```
\newenvironment{Y}{\somemacro\X}{\endX}
```

How can I achieve a similar result if X has a starred version and I want to patch X*. N.b. it is not necessary that Y has a starred version.

More specifically at the moment I have this

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{smallequation}{\def\f@size{8}\check@mathfonts\equation}{\endequation}
\newenvironment{footnoteequation}{\def\f@size{7}\check@mathfonts\equation}{\endequation}
\newenvironment{scriptsizeequation}{\def\f@size{6}\check@mathfonts\equation}{\endequation}
\newenvironment{tinyequation}{\def\f@size{5}\check@mathfonts\equation}{\endequation}
\makeatother
```

This is the result of the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation). However, now I want to do the same but for the equation*-environment.

Comment: You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: You can use `\newenvironment{Y}{\somemacro\begin{X*}}{\end{X*}}`. You might also want to look at section 3.4 of the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\csname equation*\endcsname
\csname endequation*\endcsname
```

For instance

```
\newenvironment{smallequation*}
  {\def\f@size{8}\check@mathfonts\csname equation*\endcsname}
  {\csname endequation*\endcsname}
```