# Equation number is not coming in end line of equation in two-column document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn]{revtex4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.45}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
2F_1(a,b,c,y){=}\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-
b)}~_2F_1(a,b,a+b-c+1,1-y)+\\   
\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(a+b-c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}(1-y)^{c-a-
b}~_2F_1(c-a,c-b,c-a-b+1,1-y)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

In two column document class,Equation number is not coming on the line where equation ends, instead it comes in next line,  please help ??

Comment: Thy do you post the same question twice? As already stated, the content of your equation is too wide. The eq number doesn't fit.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Sorry, But could you please tell me how to reduce the size so as to get the equation number in same line ??

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation

Comment: reducing the font size to make the equation harder to read, just to stop the class specified behaviour of putting the number on the next line should be a non-aim