# Redefining the equation and align environment to use a different font size

Tags: equations, align, fontsize

How do I redefine the `equation` and `align` environment to use a font size of `9.0pt`? I found this nice [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60459/73467) (*apart from starting a new paragraph after applying it*), allowing me to define the font size of a single `equation` or `align` environment:

```
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{9.0}\check@mathfonts
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}\endgroup
```

or without adjusting the equation number is fine as well:

```
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{9.0}\check@mathfonts
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}\endgroup
```

I like to apply this globally without using different environment names.

**Edit**: some compilable example (though I have to use a different document class):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is some text.
\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5.0}\check@mathfonts
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}
\begin{equation}
P = NP
\end{equation}\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example we can compile. Look at `etoolbox`, it has macros such as `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` which you can use for this. Better, though, to use `\fontsize{}{}\selectfont`, I think.

Comment: @cfr I added something that can compile (though it does not really provide lots of added value imho).

Comment: @cfr I tried `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\begingroup\makeatletter\def\f@size{5.0}\check@mathfonts}
\AtEndEnvironment{equation}{\endgroup}`, but it doesn't compile: \check only allowed in math mode, missing $, you can't use \eqno in horizontal mode, etc. ?

Comment: You don't want `\makeatletter` inside. Put it outside with `\makeatother` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern,amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}
\let\oldequation\equation
\def\equation{\def\f@size{5.0}\check@mathfonts\oldequation}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is some text.
\begin{equation}
P = NP
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Can I just add `align` and `alignat` in the same `makeatletter`/`makeatother` pair or do I need three of these blocks?

Comment: @Matthias Yes of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can add code at the beginning of an environment using `etoolbox`. For example,

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{%
  \fontsize{5}{6}%
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
  \fontsize{5}{6}%
}
\begin{document}
This is some text.
\begin{equation}
P = NP
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  P = NP
\end{align}
Here is some more text.
\end{document}
```

[image: small maths]

Note that the use of hard-coded font sizes is not recommended. In this case, it would be better to replace `\fontsize{5}{6}` by, say, `\tiny`, which is equivalent for a document with `10pt` as the default size. This helps ensure consistency and makes your code more flexible.

Comment: I know it is not the most clean solution, but I need to use a certain template for a paper. Most of my equation numbers do not fit the same line, therefore, I want to slightly reduce the font size. This improves readability as well since the text and formulas have a slightly different size.