# How to reduce the equation font size in math mode in Latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize, scaling

I am trying to resize the equation font size in math mode:

As [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60458/193620)
 suggested :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%
\begin{document}
\[y = \sin^2 x\]
%
\[\Scale[0.5]{y = \sin^2 x}\]
%
\[ \Resize{1cm}{y = \sin^2 x}\]
\end{document}
```

Where my equation look like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{H_{2}^{(l+1)}=\sigma(\alpha_{22}^{(l)} H_{2}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{21}^{(l)} H_{1}^{(l)} W^{(l)}  \\
 +\alpha_{23}^{(l)} H_{3}^{(l)} W^{(l)}+\alpha_{24}^{(l)} H_{4}^{(l)} W^{(l)} )}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

it's going outside of paper width.

How to reduce the font or use this code to reduce font of equation inside paper width?

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Line breaking is preferred over shrinking the font size.

Comment: If you want to have the whole equation in bold face you could use `\boldmath\begin{equation}...\end{equation}\unboldmath`, but I don't recommend that at all.  Bold face usually carries special semantic meaning in math and therefore cannot be used for emphasis.  Better use a different color or put a box around it, see the [`empheq`](https://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package.

Comment: The answer from David in the question you linked to is much better than using some scalebox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of shrinking the font size, it is generally better to use a line break.  For that purpose the `amsmath` package provides the `multline` environment.  From the documentation:

> The `multline` environment is a variation of the `equation` environment used for
>   equations that don't fit on a single line. The first line of a `multline` will be at the left margin and the last line at the right margin, except for an indention on
>   both sides in the amount of `\multlinegap`. Any additional lines in between will
>   be centered independently within the display width (unless the `fleqn` option is
>   in effect).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{multline}
    H_{2}^{(l+1)}
    = \sigma ( \alpha_{22}^{(l)} H_{2}^{(l)} W^{(l)} + \alpha_{21}^{(l)} H_{1}^{(l)} W^{(l)}  \\
    + \alpha_{23}^{(l)} H_{3}^{(l)} W^{(l)} + \alpha_{24}^{(l)} H_{4}^{(l)} W^{(l)} )
\end{multline}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]