# How to adjust the size of the subscript

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the Tikz environment the subscripts are appearing in the same size as the scripts themselves, How can I fix this, please?
The code I am using is the following

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]
\node at (-4.2,0){\tiny $a_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this. It may be that the lowercase `a` is smaller, causing your illusion.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$a_0$ $A_0$ $A_a$ $a_a$

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-4.2,0) {$a_0$ $A_0$ $A_a$ $a_a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Add

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle a_0$ $\textstyle A_0$ $\scriptstyle A_a$ $\scriptscriptstyle a_a$

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-4.2,0) {$\displaystyle a_0$ $\textstyle A_0$ $\scriptstyle A_a$ $\scriptscriptstyle a_a$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (-4.2,0) {$a_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}$ $\textstyle A_0$ $\scriptstyle A_a$ $a_{\scriptscriptstyle a}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mean that one can't make that subscript smaller?

Comment: @F.Marko No. It can be changed. The math font size should be change by `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the tikzpicture. You should use e.g. `\scriptstyle` instead of `\tiny` for math - see e.g. [Reducing font size in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
~\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=base] at (-4.2,0){\tiny $a_0$};
\end{tikzpicture} - TiKZPicture\\
{\tiny $a_0$} - tiny size\\
$a_0$ - normal size
\end{document}
```

[image: Math in different sizes]