# Math font family for Merriweather (black) font family

Tags: math-fonts

I want to use a strong font in my text, like `\usepackage[black]{merriweather}`, but it also has a lot of equations.
So, is there any "strong" math font I could use?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[black]{merriweather}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2] $x=4$.

\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

I can not use XeTeX or LuaTex.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/mathfonts.html)?

Comment: Your example show the effect of the `black` option in the section headings but not in the text, is that correct? So what should the maths match? Presumably you want something with (1) a bold series (2) a heavier bold series? Or ...?

Comment: @cfr In fact, I completely forgot that option on the Font Catalog .Thanks

Comment: Really, I think for TeX, it doesn't make sense to pick text fonts and then try to match in maths. You need to make your font selection for both text and maths or, failing that, pick your maths first.

Comment: I found `\usepackage{fouriernc}` on the Font Catalog. But how I set it just for math?

Comment: Does loading it before `merriweather` help? If so, that's simplest. If not, you can extract the maths set up from the `.sty` file.

Comment: No, it works fine! It was obvious. :P

Comment: Is there some way to scale the font? If it was just a little bigger...

Comment: Oh, that. That's not stupid. That's just life. It never seems obvious when it is your own problem you're trying to solve ;). There is no straightforward way to scale it. Some fonts are set up so that scaling is just a matter of setting an option appropriately, but `fouriernc`'s font definition files don't do that.

Comment: If it was text, I could adapt the `.fd` files so you could scale it. But I can't seem to do it for maths. (And `fouriernc` is relying on a kind of hierarchy of font definitions involving all kinds of files from different places, so it is hard to figure out what it is even using.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `fouriernc` for maths but Merriweather for text, just load `fouriernc` before `merriweather`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[black]{merriweather}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2] $x=4$.

\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: Merriweather & Fourier NC]

## EDIT

It is very difficult to scale the fonts for maths straightforwardly, but, as you pointed out, it is possible to alter the point sizes LaTeX uses for maths using code from [Stefan Kottwitz's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5152/).

For example, to use the settings which are default for 12pt text in an 11pt document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[black]{merriweather}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xiipt}{8}{6}% modified from fontmath.ltx
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2] $x=4$.

\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}

\[
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n! + \dots 1}}{\prod_{k=i^{j^n}} \exp^k - \pi\delta }
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: display maths sizes from 12pt for 11pt]

Note that, unlike font scaling, this must be done for every fontsize context in which you will use mathematics.

To illustrate, suppose that we'd set maths to be huge:

```
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

(These sizes correspond to the largest text size LaTeX uses by default.)

Now suppose that we typeset the following

```
\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}

\small
\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}
```

Normally, we'd expect the second to be slightly smaller than the first. For example, with the default settings

[image: standard]

However, with our enormous maths we will get the following mismatch

[image: mismatched]

This is because `\small` alters the current text size and LaTeX chooses the sizes for maths according to the current text size. Because we didn't alter the sizes declared for `\small`, the default, much, much smaller settings are used.

Similarly, `\large` will have somewhat counterintuitive effects

```
\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}

\large
\begin{displaymath}
\Delta G^{\circ}= -R\,T\ln \dfrac{[S_1][S_2]}{[S_1S_2]}.
\end{displaymath}
```

[image: Wonderland sizing?]

That is, `\large` makes text bigger and maths smaller.

To avoid this, it would be best to redefine all the standard sizes LaTeX uses proportionately to avoid ending up with subtle inconsistencies in the size of maths.

Comment: I have found a solution to Math size: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-math-equations) `\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{x}{y}{z}`

Comment: @cfr I really didn't know that. Could you possible add if there are any sideeffects to this, and why it only effects math?

Comment: The first entry must be the font size of the document (11 pt= 10.95). Also, the first option of `\documentclass` must be the size too.

Comment: @runartrollet Please see edit. It only affects maths because LaTeX only uses maths font sizes in maths mode. I realise that sounds circular and it is: it is just the way LaTeX defines and uses these settings.

Comment: @CostaPR Please see edit. Ideally, you should do this for all standard sizes. Certainly, you may wish to do it for more than 11pt in an 11pt document.