# Font size in equation block and how to change it globally

Tags: equations, displaystyle

I am trying to know what font size is used in equation block:

```
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
```

And I stuck because I cannot found it anywhere on the Internet. Not even know how to change the size of equation, but how to know the default or current font size. I found that in equation block \displaystyle font style is used, but I don't know what size it is using.

Here is my settings in TeX code (I used Basic Paper in Overleaf):

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english} 
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
```

Comment: I guess it will be a 10pt font, the default. If you use the class option `11pt` or `12pt`, the whole document will be typeset in a larger font. You can selectively choose a larger font for the equation by saying something like `{\LARGE\begin{equation}...\end{equation}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60453/reducing-font-size-in-equation or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5148/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-in-math-equations. Perphaps you can resolve the your problem .I agree with the answer given by Gernot. In `\documentclass{article}` you must use class option `11pt` or `12pt`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out somehow. Here is the code:

```
\newcommand{\mathfontsize}{14pt}

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{myequation}{
    \begin{equation}
    \fontsize{\mathfontsize}{\mathfontsize*1.2}\selectfont
    \BODY
    \end{equation}
}

% Using:

\begin{myequation}
    {\symit \Gamma} + \Sigma
\end{myequation}
```

I don't remember where I found some parts of it, some code I found here, some not. But overall, thank you for participating!

Comment: See our comments. As he wrote Gernot, it is easier the solution, `{\LARGE\begin{equation}...\end{equation}}`. You try with Papeeria.